# I can't replace line breaks in vim and iterm

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, iterm2, control-characters

In Vim in iTerm, I frequently encounter issues surrounding line breaks. For example, if I have a file containing the dreaded ^M most online tutorials will say that to perform a replacement I use a regular find and replace on a file like:

```
%s/^M/^J/g
```

My problem is that I am unable to enter the ^M - when I type ^V^M (control+V control+M) what is inserted is actually ^J. The result of this replacement is "no occurences found". Am I doing something wrong or could VIM or iTerm be misconfigured somehow?

Some extra info:

1. This also occurs in `/usr/bin/vi` in the Terminal app when `set compatible` is on
2. Here is an example line through hexdump, which shows the line breaks after the closing square brackets as hex char 0d, which I believe is ^M

`00000120  3c 2f 6c 6f 63 3e 0d 20  20 3c 2f 75 72 6c 3e 0d  |</loc>.  </url>.|`

Comment: Does ^V followed by enter work?

Comment: Same thing, it shows ^J

Comment: I should point out as well, using the hex code for `0d` also produces ^J ie `^VX0d` produces ^J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit, looks like it was the pathogen plugin `vim-sensible`.  I simply deleted pathogen plugins from ~/vim/bundle and re-tested until it worked.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Can you expand your answer a little to explain what you did to solve it?

Comment: I really don't have much insight on the issue. I deleted pathogen plugins from ~/vim/bundle and re-tested until it worked. Presumably vim-sensible thinks it is sensible to transform line endings in user inputs (ie pasted data, keyboard inputs) from windows to unix style.